# Xpath not finding element (parent/ancestor)

Tags: selenium, xpath

```
<div class="slds-show" data-aura-rendered-by="10155:0">
<div class="footer" data-aura-rendered-by="10156:0">
    <div class="slds-grid slds-grid--align-end slds-m-top--large" data-aura-rendered-by="10157:0">
        <div class="slds-show" data-aura-rendered-by="10158:0">
            <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-m-left--small" data-aura-rendered-by="10159:0">Cancel</button>
            <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-m-left--small" data-aura-rendered-by="10161:0">Save &amp; New</button>
            <button class="slds-button slds-button--brand slds-m-left--small" data-aura-rendered-by="10163:0">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is part of page, on which I will have to click on Save button. 
Button is not unique and I need to find it throu class attribute from first div (slds-show), or

Can somebody tell me, why this xpath is not finding this element?

```
//button[parent::div[@class='slds-show'][@class='slds-button slds-button--brand slds-m-left--small']]
```

I've also try with ancestor, text instead of class and results is the same. Element is not found via Firefox console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update your expression as below:

```
//button[parent::div[@class='slds-show'] and @class='slds-button slds-button--brand slds-m-left--small']
```

Note that predicate `[@class='slds-button slds-button--brand slds-m-left--small']` in your XPath intend to test `@class` value of parent `div`, but not target `button`

Comment: This one works, but due to content of page, I have to results. In case if using ancestor with upper node I have four results... I think I will have to contact dev to fix that

Answer (score 1):

To click on ***Save*** button once finding it through *class* attribute from *first div (slds-show)* you can use a much simpler and effective *xpath* as follows :

```
//div[@class='slds-show']/button[@class='slds-button slds-button--brand slds-m-left--small']
```

> **Note** : The class attribute *`slds-button--brand`* is unique for the ***Save*** button.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following xpaths.

1. `//*[@class="slds-show"]/button[text()="Save"]`

or

2. `//*[class="slds-show"]/button[@class="slds-button slds-button--brand slds-m-left--small"]`

Answer (score 0):

An xpath can easily get too complex, you can also try something like this:

- `//button[text()='Cancel']`
- `//button[text()='Save & New']`
- `//button[text()='Save']`

These will return the exact buttons you need. If you're looking for a specific ancestor, include it in your xpath:

`//div[@class="slds-show"]//button[text()='Save & New']`